# How to cite lecture slides?

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

I want to cite lecture slides using IEEE style as described here: https://libraryguides.vu.edu.au/ieeereferencing/lecturenotes

The lecture notes are here: http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture11.pdf

How to include this in LaTeX?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add a minimal example: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give enough details to answer.

According to [How to Use the IEEEtran BiBTeX Style](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf):

> IEEEtran.bst provides the electronic entry type for internet
> references. IEEEtran.bst also provides the aliases “online”,
> “internet”, “webpage” and “www” for compatibility with some existing
> BiBTeX database and style files. However, “electronic” (or perhaps
> “online” for those who also use Philipp Lehman’s `biblatex`) should be
> used for all new work. The IEEE formats electronic references
> differently by not using italics or quotes and separating fields with
> periods rather than commas. Also, the date is enclosed within
> parentheses and is placed closer to the title. This is probably done
> to emphasize that electronic references may not remain valid on the
> rapidly changing internet. Note also the liberal use of the
> howpublished field to describe the form or category of the entries.
> The organization and address fields may also be used.

Supposing you're using `IEEEtran` document class, here is an example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@online{li2017,
  author = {Fei-Fei Li and Justin Johnson and Serena Yeung},
  title = {{Lecture 11: Detection and Segmentation}},
  url = {http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture11.pdf},
  howpublished={PDF document},
  year = {2017}
}
@article{duck2023,
  author = {Paulinho van Duck and Paulette de la Quack},
  title = {{Ducks are smart}},
  journal={{Quack University Journal}},
  volume={1},
  number={3},
  year = {2023}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[american]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}
Lecture note: \cite{li2017}.

Ordinary article: \cite{duck2023}.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `\usepackage{xurl}` to auto breakline.

Comment: @Clara Done, thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: And `_` is worked, no need `\_` in url.

Comment: @Clara Corrected, thank you again! I modified it to do some tests and after I forgot to restore it to the original.